# How do I hide the top bar in Ubuntu (GNOME Shell)?

Tags: panel, gnome-shell, autohide

Is there any possibility to autohide the panel in GNOME 3 session?
In picture below I selected the area what I mean.

[image: Ubuntu 15.10 gnome 3.18 top panel image]

Comment: @incBrain GNOME and compiz are completely different things.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using the [GNOME extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Hide Top Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/).

[image]

Configure the extension in your Firefox or with <kbd>Tweak Tool</kbd>

[image]

Comment: If you are puzzled about exactly where in the **Tweak Tool** the above is to be found, it is under Extensions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB1Fa.png

Comment: Word of caution: The side panel also shows up which is also something you might need. You can control this also from the Tweak Tool at the bottom: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKdh5.png

Answer (score 19):

I was able to achieve the behavior you want in the following way in my Ubuntu 18.04.

1. Installed **Dash to Panel** GNOME Shell Extension.
   To install it, simply search for "Dash to Panel" in Ubuntu Software.
2. Once installed, right clicked on "show apps" button on task bar and clicked "Dash to Panel Settings".
3. I chose Panel *Intellihide* "On".
4. You may edit more settings by clicking "settings button" adjacent to *Intellihide*

[image: Dash to panel]
[image: top right corner]
[image: settings]
[image: intellihide on]

Comment: Nice, but this forces the panel at top or bottom position, not left or right :-/

Answer (score 5):

### Unite Extension

[image: Unite Extension]

try https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/. It brings back the Unity Shell look and feel to Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: If only Dash-to-Panel and Unite worked well together :)