# 18.04 Hide Panel and keep clock

Tags: gnome, 18.04, panel, clock

Is there a way to hide the Panel and keep the clock somewhere else in Gnome?

Comment: (Auto-)hiding top bar may be possible: https://askubuntu.com/questions/720617/how-to-hide-gnome-top-panel

Comment: I know this extension, but I was thinking about something like putting the clock in the dock or something. I like to have a clock on my screen and to be able to look at it without moving the mouse, but I hate the top bar. It is virtually useless. The only thing it is good at is consuming space from the desktop which is extremely annoying. The info contained in the top bar could be put anywhere else, like in the dock bar. Thank you anyway :)