# GNOME 3 merge top bar and Ubuntu dock (side/bottom bar)

Tags: customization, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Is there a way to merge to two bars in GNOME 3? Best case scenario would be to have one single bottom or top bar that has all the symbols on the left side and the rest like the time indicator, connections, on/off button, etc. on the right side.

Is that possible in any way?

Comment: Yes, use "Dash to Panel" GNOME extension. See this answer for reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/1050683/480481

Comment: @pomsky That would be the perfect answer to this particular question.

Comment: @pomsky can't we create a short-key to hide Top Bar? That would be really cool idea. But can we?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The **Dash to Panel** Gnome Shell extension does exactly what you want and is highly configurable.

You can install it from Ubuntu software (search *Dash to panel*), or using the terminal with the command `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel`. Caveat: the extension is not automatically enabled. Log out and then back in. Then you will see the extension in Gnome Tweaks, and you can enable it there.

Alternatively, you can install the extension from [Gnome extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/). This does not immediately work on a fresh Ubuntu install. See [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) (answer by user364819) on how to enable installing Gnome Extensions from the website on Ubuntu.

To configure the extension, make sure you have "Gnome Tweaks" installed. In Gnome Tweaks, find the extension on the *Extensions* tab and click the cog icon to access the settings.

Comment: Ok, installing "Dash to Panel` from the software center worked and also does the trick. But using `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel` does not work.

Comment: It does work. However, it is a system wide extension and it is not enabled automatically. Also, you may need to log out and log in again before the extension appears in Tweaks. I will indicate that in my answer.

Comment: @vanadium if u could upload the picture it would have encourage a newbie like me. Please. I wanna see it, how it looks?

Comment: I couldn't get them to merge, only to have two separate bars :/

Comment: @AdamGoldman Then you did not succeed in succesfully installing Dash to Panel. Or perhaps you installed Dash to Dock rather than Dash to Panel?

Comment: @vanadium do you have a screenshot of that working? I'd love to see it. For now I'm hiding my dock, positioned at the bottom of the screen with transparent background

Comment: @AdamGoldman, a screenshot will not help. As soon as the extension is successfully installed and turned on (Gnome Tweaks), you will have a single Windows 10-like bar at the bottom. Disable other extensions that manipulate dock and bar such as Ubuntu Dock or Dash to Dock before enabling Dash To Panel.

Comment: On Ubuntu 23.04.

`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel `outputs:
`Package gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.
E: Package 'gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel' has no installation candidate.`

Searching 'Dash to Panel' in Software Center also gave no hit.

Searching 'dash-to-panel' in https://packages.ubuntu.com only gave a hit for Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Does this extension require the `universe` repository?

Answer (score 0):

Install Gnome Tweaks with two steps

- `sudo add-apt-repository universe`
- `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`

Install the extension **Dash to Panel** answered by @vanadium .

- `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel`