# How can I disable the top bar to get more screen space?

Tags: gnome-shell, screen, fullscreen

I've just disabled the dock that's on the left-hand side of the screen from **Extensions > Built-In > Ubuntu dock**

I'm wondering how to disable the bar that's on the top so that can get fullscreen

[image: TOP]

Has to be pretty straightforward but I cannot manage it.

Any help? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide GNOME 3 panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720617/how-do-i-hide-gnome-3-panel)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [Just Perfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) extension.

- See this for how to install GNOME Shell extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)

After installing the extension:

1. Open Extensions and find *Just Perfection* in the list of extensions.

   [image: Extensions]
2. Toggle the extension on.

   [image: Toggle]
3. Click on the gear icon next to the extension toggle.

   [image: Gear icon]
4. In the window that opens toggle *Panel* off in the *Visibility* section.

   [image: Just Perfection]

That's it. The extension also allows you to change many more things of GNOME Shell.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response !

Comment: Using the Just Perfection extension, you can still see the top bar when toggling the overview (by pressing the Super key) if you enable *Panel In Overview*. This feature [was added in version 16.0.0 Rembrandt](https://gitlab.gnome.org/jrahmatzadeh/just-perfection/-/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#1600-rembrandt-2021-11-15).

Answer (score 3):

If for browser only, as per your example, hit <kbd>F11</kbd>.
This will stretch your browser to the outer edges of your screen for maximum real estate.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response !

Answer (score 3):

[Hide Top Bar by tuxor1337](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/) is a dedicated extension to hide the top bar from the desktop view. It will remain available in the Activities overview.

The extension is configurable. You also can have it "intellihide", where it hides only when a window takes the space.

[Just Perfection by JustPerfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) is a general extension that allows you to tweak several aspects of the Gnome Desktop. It also includes an option to hide the top bar. However, here, it is an "all-or-nothing" setting: when you disable the top bar, it is fully gone, even in the Activities overview.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response !